# Calculate MD5 of all files excluding those of a list

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep, find

I have a lot of files inside my directory

```
/home/files/*
```

I also have a .txt File that contains the path to some files of my directory, e.g.

```
/home/files/file1
/home/files/file2
...
```

Now I'd like to calculate the MD5 sum of all files inside my directory without the ones listed in my .txt-file.

Until now I've following code:

```
find /home/files/* -type f -mmin -5 -exec grep /home/list.txt md5sum {} >> /home/MD5.txt \;
```

What do I have do change that this will work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
find  /home/files/* -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -qv "$1" /home/list.txt && md5sum "$1"' - {} \; >/home/MD5.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `find` and `xargs` :

```
find /home/files/* -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 bash -c 'grep -qL "${1##*/}" /home/list.txt || md5sum "$1"' \; > md5.txt
```

Comment: Great! Furthermore this is one is more flexible within the file handling.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively with **for** and **if** :)
File with files list:

```
cat /home/centos/list.txt
/home/centos/files/1
/home/centos/files/3
```

Directory:

```
ls files/
1  2  3  4  5
```

Command:

```
for i in `ls -d -1 /home/centos/files/*`; do if [ `grep -e $i list.txt` ]; then md5sum $i >> md5.txt; fi; done;
```

File with md5s:

```
cat md5.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/centos/files/1
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/centos/files/3
```

Comment: I think that's a good way if you'd like to have a look at files older/younger than days. Unfortunately it won't work with minutes. But thanks for sharing.